# Customer EAV attribute error: "Mobile Number" is a required value

Tags: magento2, customer, eav

I have created a custom attribute to store the users mobile number on registration. It's visible on the registration, and admin page, but upon trying to create a customer I get the following error:

```
"Mobile Number" is a required value.
```

Here's the class:

```
<?php

namespace JR2\ExtraCustomerData\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class AddMobilePhoneAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, UninstallInterface
{
    private $attributeName = 'mobile_number';
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $logger;
    private $eavConfig;
    private $attributeResource;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        Config $eavConfig,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource,
        \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    )
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        $this->addMobilePhoneAttribute();
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function addMobilePhoneAttribute()
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create([ 'setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup ]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                $this->attributeName,
                [
                    'type'          => 'varchar',
                    'label'         => 'Mobile Number',
                    'input'         => 'text',
                    'required'      => 1,
                    'visible'       => 1,
                    'user_defined'  => 1,
                    'sort_order'    => 999,
                    'position'      => 999,
                    'system'        => 0
                ]
        );
        
        $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);
        
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                $this->attributeName
        );

        $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
        $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [ 'adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create' ]);

        $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
    }
    
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function uninstall(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create([ 'setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup ]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, $this->attributeName);
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

And the following phtml template:

```
<div class="field mobile_number required">
   <label class="label" for="mobile_number">
       <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Mobile Number')) ?></span>
   </label>
   <div class="control">
       <input type="tel" name="mobile_number" id="mobile_number" value="" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
   </div>
</div>
```

I've checked the POST data sent with the request and the `mobile_number` field is definitely being sent. I've checked the docs and can't seem to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Make required false when create attribute. Change From 'required'=> 1 to 'required'=> 0

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        $this->attributeName,
        [
            'type'          => 'varchar',
            'label'         => 'Mobile Number',
            'input'         => 'text',
            'required'      => 0,
            'visible'       => 1,
            'user_defined'  => 1,
            'sort_order'    => 999,
            'position'      => 999,
            'system'        => 0
        ]
);
```

> 2. Make required false in html code. from data-validate="{required:true} to data-validate="{required:false} and remove required class

```
<div class="field mobile_number">
   <label class="label" for="mobile_number">
       <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Mobile Number')) ?></span>
   </label>
   <div class="control">
       <input type="tel" name="mobile_number" id="mobile_number" value="" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false}">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But, it's a required parameter so why would I set it as optional? The problem I have is even when I'm sending the `mobile_number` POST data attribute, the response is: `"Mobile Number" is a required value.`

Comment: I run your code in my setup and it's working fine. Check is there any third-party module which making an issue? try to disable third party module and check and run upgrade, compile command.

Comment: I reprovisioned my server, added module, and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

For any EAV attribute that is required (like mobile number), you can set it unrequired while creating it or after creation from database table.

1. While creating it using InstallData.php or UpgradeData.php

   ```
   $eavSetup->addAttribute(
           \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,'mobile_number',
           [
               'type'          => 'varchar',
               'label'         => 'Mobile Number',
               'input'         => 'text',
               'required'      => 0,
               'visible'       => 1,
               'user_defined'  => 1,
               'sort_order'    => 150,
               'position'      => 999,
               'system'        => 0
           ]
   );
   ```
2. In Eav Attribute table "eav_attribute", search for that attribute "mobile_number" and set required to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make `Mobile Number` as Optional Parameter.
In your code, change `required` from `1` to `0`, see below code.

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                $this->attributeName,
                [
                    'type'          => 'varchar',
                    'label'         => 'Mobile Number',
                    'input'         => 'text',
                    'required'      => 0,
                    'visible'       => 1,
                    'user_defined'  => 1,
                    'sort_order'    => 999,
                    'position'      => 999,
                    'system'        => 0
                ]
        );
```

In your `PHTML` file remove `required` class and `data-validate="{required:true}`  attribute also. Your code will look like -

```
<div class="field mobile_number">
   <label class="label" for="mobile_number">
       <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Mobile Number')) ?></span>
   </label>
   <div class="control">
       <input type="tel" name="mobile_number" id="mobile_number" value="" class="input-text">
   </div>
</div>
```